# How to force MATLAB to return all values in a nested function call?

Tags: matlab, function, cell-array

I find it impossible to write MATLAB code without creating a huge number of superfluous, single-use variables.

For example, suppose function `foo` returns three column vectors of exactly the same size.  Say:

```
function [a, b, c] = foo(n)
    a = rand(n, 1);
    b = rand(n, 1);
    c = rand(n, 1);
end
```

Now, suppose that `bar` is a function that expect as imput a cell array of size `(1, 3)`.

```
function result = bar(triplet)
    [x, y, z] = triplet{:};
    result = x + y + z;
end
```

If I want to pass the results of `foo(5)`, I can do it by creating three otherwise-useless variables:

```
[x, y, z] = foo(5);
result = bar({x, y, z});
```

Is there some function `baz` that would allow me to replace the two lines above with

```
result = bar(baz(foo(5)));
```

?

NB: the functions `foo` and `bar` above are meant only as examples.  They're supposed to represent functions over which I have no control.  IOW, modifying them is not an option.

Comment: Are these functions over which you have no control MATLAB's or those of your peers?

Comment: Are you sure that the functions return a constant number of outputs, or can it also be `varargout`?

Comment: @Dev-iL: what would you do if `foo` were `varargout`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not possible. `baz` in `baz(foo(5))` will only take the first output of `foo`, the other two would be ignored. The plain two-line variant is not that awkward. And this is not a common situation. You don't generally work with cell arrays where normal numerical arrays would do.

You could of course just write your own wrapper for `foo` that returns whatever you need (i.e. containing similar two lines), in case you need to use it frequently.

Answer (score 3):

You can replace the three variables by a cell array using a [comma-separated list](http://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html):

```
vars = cell(1,3);     % initiallize cell array with as many elements as outputs of foo
[vars{:}] = foo(5);   % comma-separated list: each cell acts as a variable that 
                      % receives an output of foo
result = bar(vars);
```

Comment: This is not really what was asked.. the question was whether it can can done inline, without temporary variables. The answer is simply, **no**.

Comment: @nirvana-msu but he introduced a third function `baz`

Comment: @ebh, exactly. The question was literally whether it can be done like `bar(baz(foo(5)))`. Again, the answer is simply no. What's the point trying to twist the question. There's plenty of other questions asking how to collect multiple outputs.

Comment: @nirvana-msu if you're going to crow about answering the literal question then just change `vars` to `result` and you now accomplish the task without using "a huge number of superfluous, single-use variables" as the OP *literally* states. Plus you get the added bonus of preallocation. How wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

As [nirvana-msu said,](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38213956/6469393) it is not possible to do the task without creating temporary variables. But it is possible to handle it within a function and even with `varargin` and `varargout`. Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39360719/6469393) on [my question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359410/how-to-directly-pass-multiple-outputs-of-a-function-to-another/39360719#39360719), you can define and use the following function:

```
function varargout = redirect(F1, F2, count, list, varargin)
    output = cell(1, count);
    [output{:}] = F2(varargin{:});
    varargout = cell(1, max(nargout, 1));
    [varargout{:}] = F1(output(list));
end
```

For instance, in your example you can write `result = redirect(@bar, @foo, 3, [1:3], 5);`

Answer (score 0):

The issue is you are converting the cell triplet{} into an array[], so a conversion is the method you want. Although [this method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/num2cell.html?searchHighlight=convert%20cell%20to%20array) will perform the inverse transformation, I know of no method that will perform the transformation you want, likely due to the relative complexity of the cell data structure. You may have some luck further digging into the API.

EDIT: EBH kindly pointed out [this method](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html), which does what you are looking for.

EDIT2: The above method will not perform the action OP asked for. Leaving this up because the API often has great solutions that are hidden by bad names.

Comment: The issue is not in converting cell array to multiple variables. The issue is in capturing multiple outputs without intermediate variables.

Comment: @b-bush for the opposite conversion there is [`cell2mat`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/cell2mat.html)

Comment: The issue is bar will not accept the output of foo--an array--so this output must be converted into a cell. The method baz he is asking for would do exactly this, hopefully without using trash variables to do so as you said. Perhaps I should have stressed this in my answer, but it is on topic.

Comment: @B.Bush if you just write `result = bar(cell2mat(foo(5)))` then you will get an error because `foo(5)` will only return `x`

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the advantage of either method over the explicit array concatenation of the original question.

Comment: @excaza there is no advantage, it's not even working. The issue is not about conversion but about grasping 3 outputs into one output variable

Comment: @EBH yes, I understand the issue.