# How to directly pass multiple outputs of a function to another?

Tags: matlab, function, arguments, octave

Let me elaborate with **examples:** We know how to easily combine functions with a single output:

```
a = sin(sqrt(8));
```

Now consider this example code containing two steps to calculate `R`, with `X` and `Y` as intermediate outputs.

```
[X, Y] = meshgrid(-2:2, -2:2);
[~, R] = cart2pol(X, Y);
```

**In general** is there a way to combine the two functions and get rid of intermediate outputs? For instance how can I write something similar to `[~, R] = cart2pol(meshgrid(-2:2, -2:2))` that works same as the previous code?

**Note:** What makes my question different from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213814/how-to-force-matlab-to-return-all-values-in-a-nested-function-call) is that in my case the outer function accepts multiple inputs. Therefore I cannot and do not want to combine the outputs of the first function into one cell array. I want them to be passed to the second function separately.

Comment: if you want a specific answer just for this example, the `cart2pol` function requires exactly 2 inputs and by giving it the output of the meshgrid `[X Y]` you are giving it a single matrix as input.

Comment: Actually I just wanted to make an example with mentioning `cart2pol`. I will modify my post.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to force MATLAB to return all values in a nested function call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38213814/how-to-force-matlab-to-return-all-values-in-a-nested-function-call)

Comment: @EBH differences explained.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**To answer the question in the title:** Using the following function, it is possible to redirect multiple outputs of a function to another:

```
function varargout = redirect(source, destination, n_output_source, which_redirect_from_source, varargin)
%(redirect(source, destination, n_output_source, which_redirect_from_source,....)
%redirect output of a function (source) to input of another function(destination)
% source: function pointer
% destination: function pointer
% n_output_source: number of outputs of source function (to select best overload function)
% which_redirect_from_source: indices of outputs to be redirected
% varargin arguments to source function
    output = cell(1, n_output_source);
    [output{:}] = source(varargin{:});
    varargout = cell(1, max(nargout,1));
    [varargout{:}] = destination(output{which_redirect_from_source});
end
```

And now we can apply it to the example:

```
[~,R] = redirect(@meshgrid,@cart2pol, 2, [1, 2], -2:2, -2:2)
```

Here, source function has 2 outputs and we want to redirect outputs 1 and 2 from source to destination. -2:2 is the input argument of the source function.

---

**Other way to deal with the mentioned example:** If you can use GNU Octave, with `bsxfun` and `nthargout` this is your solution:

```
R = bsxfun(@(a,b) nthargout(2, @cart2pol,a,b),(-2:2)',(-2:2))
```

in Matlab a possible solution is:

```
[~, R] = cart2pol(meshgrid(-2:2), transpose(meshgrid(-2:2)))
```

or

```
function R = cart2pol2(m)
    [~,R] = cart2pol(m,m')
end

cart2pol2(meshgrid(-2:2, -2:2))
```

Comment: Although this solution probably work, it doesn't look a lot better. The two line approach at least makes it clear for future users what you are doing.

Comment: @Bernhard I agree. much of popularity of Matlab language is due to its expressiveness. However this answer is provided as a workaround