# Passing two values from one Matlab function to another in one line

Tags: matlab, function

I'm looking to pass the outputs of a two-output function into a two-input function, in one line.

i.e. if I have two functions

```
function [out1, out2] = funA(in)
%function definition here
function out = funB(in1, in2)
%function definition here
```

I want to do something like

```
out = funB(funA(in)) %this doesn't actually work
```

Is there syntax to do this without having to write it as

```
[o1, o2] = funA(in)
out = funB(o1, o2)
```

I'm also not looking for

```
[o1, o2] = funA(in); out = funB(o1, o2);
```

Comment: You cant do this "easly". You can try by redifing things in matlab, as shown in [How to directly pass multiple outputs of a function to another?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359410/how-to-directly-pass-multiple-outputs-of-a-function-to-another).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/39359410/2627163

Comment: Even if people show you how to do it, its obfuscated and not that of an improvement. I suggest you keep graving `o1` and `o2` and passing them as values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is possible as if you call the function in-line with another call, Matlab will always assume that you *only* want the first/primary output.

Matlab only creates the other output variables (out2/in2 here) if you actually assign them.