# MATLAB: How to access the nth output of a function from another function

Tags: arrays, matlab, function, output, multipleoutputs

If I have a function:

```
function [out1,out2,...] = functionName[in1,in2]
function code here
end
```

And another function

```
function[newout1,newout2] = newfunctionName[in1,in2]
[newout1]=out1+out2;
[newout2]=out2+out3;
```

How do I go about calling the various outputs, out1, out2, out3 etc...

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/q/39359410/6579744

Comment: You call `functionName` from inside `newfunctionName` and get the outputs. I'm really not sure what the question is here.

Comment: @beaker If `newfunctionName` is recursive, and say `if n=1  newout1=5;  newout2=10;  else  [newout1,newout2]=functionName(newfunctionName(n/2),**out2**)` how would I get the `out2`

Comment: Please add clarifications to the question itself by editing; code in comments is impossible to read and the question should be complete and self-contained.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand very well what you meant by "calling the various outputs, out1, out2, out3 etc" but to answer the title's question,

In order to access the nth output of any function you would have to first call [nargout](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/nargout.html) on that function's name and then insert its output into a cell of preallocated size. Sample code below,

```
n = 5;
nout = abs(nargout('functionName'));
if n>nout
    error(['n must be lower or equal than ',num2str(nout)])
end
out = cell(1,n);
[out{:}] = functionName(in1,in2);
nth_output = out{n};
```

This could be done inside any function that has `functionName` in its path.